# Android - Workaround the ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY permission?

Tags: android, shell, permission-denied, android-permissions

I'm building an application which gives this exception because i call some internal methods

> Permission Denial: Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() from pid=2520, uid=10047 requires android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: Do not have permission in call getContentProviderExternal() from pid=2520, uid=10047 requires android.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT_PROVIDERS_EXTERNALLY

I did some search and i knew that android OS gives this permission only for the shell users,
I wonder if there exists any workaround this ..

Is there anything that would allow me to trick android and makes my application looks like a shell user?

Note: I tried to add the permission in the manifest file but obviously it didn't work.

Comment: I can't imagine Android allowing this kind of security circumvention. Maybe if you explain what you're trying to achieve, people can suggest an alternative way of achieve the same end.

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I'm having it in my app in which I'm trying to run a test with uiautomator. Thx.